# Self Hosted WCF Programattic HTTPS?

Tags: wcf, soap, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate installed and netsh/httpcfg setup. I am trying to create a WCF (.NET 4.0) service in a Windows Service / console app, that has all of the settings prepared programatically so clients can connect with HTTPS and not just HTTP. The documentation I could find seems to lean towards making clients use net.tcp:// protocol or something, but my clients are actually web service SOAP 1.1 clients, so I want them to get to my console app using HTTPS.

How can I make this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible. You need to use httpcfg.exe to reserve the port/path you want your self-hosted service to use and configure the SSL certificate to use on the service, and then the rest is just getting the WCF configuration right.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFSSL.aspx) will probably point you in the right direction.